# which book is the most rigorous and comprehensive book of Arendt's pracitcal philosophy?

Tags: political-philosophy, arendt

I read a book of Arendt, "Lectures on Kant's Political Philosophy" because of the recommendation of a professor.

I'm interested in her theoretical structure of practical philosophy.

are there books of her which consist of thorough and comprehensive argumentation?

for example, "Origins of Totalitarianism", "Jerusalem's Eichmann", etc. are considered as great books of her, but I would like to know these famous books are enough comprehensive or rigorous to grasp her whole theoretical structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most comprehensive book of hers, especially regarding practical philosophy, is *The Human Condition*.

The other books are rather applications of her philosophical anthropology laid out there, if at all. She is not exactly a systematic philosopher. But if you are looking for her basic theoretical background and assumptions that frame her practical philosophy, *The Human Condition* is the place where you will find it.